# Need 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' solution

Tags: c#, image, visual-studio, exception

```
if (Int32.Parse(strTotals) == 0 && nTotalCount != 0)
{
    nTotalCount = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < 66; j++)
    {
        if (GameHistoryPicBox1[j].InvokeRequired)
        {
            GameHistoryPicBox1[j].BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(() =>
            {
                if ((j + j / 6) % 2 == 0)
                    GameHistoryPicBox1[j].Image = Properties.Resources.al1;  // Line2
                else
                    GameHistoryPicBox1[j].Image = Properties.Resources.al2;  // Line4
            }));
        }
        else
        {
            if ((j + j / 6) % 2 == 0)
                GameHistoryPicBox1[j].Image = Properties.Resources.al1;
            else
                GameHistoryPicBox1[j].Image = Properties.Resources.al2;
        }
    }
}
```

I have been checking `nTotalCount` value by using thread.

If `nTotalCount` is zero, then I must clean all game picture box image.

So I was implement above code.

Unfortunately, I got the error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException'

on Line 2 and 4.

And the `j` value was `66`.

Is it possible that `j` value could be `66`?

Comment: `BeginInvoke()` is async.  That completely breaks your logic.  You shouldn't do that inside a loop.

Comment: Um... To access UI Control from Thread, BeginInvoke must call. Isn't it?

Comment: Add a delegate to handle to calls to the UI thread

Comment: @bTagTiger: Yes, but it is broken (and also extremely slow) to do that separately for each iteration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of how closures work. Your lambda expression that you're creating and passing to the `MethodInvoker` references the `j` variable by reference. Thus when this piece of code is being executed (which can be almost any time, as it's asynchronous) the `j` variable can have any value from `0` to `66`. And it can be `66` after the loop has finished.

A quick fix is to make a copy of `j`:

```
int index = j;
GameHistoryPicBox1[index].BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(() =>
    {
        if ((index + index / 6) % 2 == 0)
            GameHistoryPicBox1[index].Image = Properties.Resources.al1;  // Line2
        else
            GameHistoryPicBox1[index].Image = Properties.Resources.al2;  // Line4
    }));
```

You can read more about this [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/rajeevr/archive/2012/02/26/closures-and-captured-variable.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

The variable `j` is being passed into the closure, and because the call is asynchronous, it is  actually executed at some point *after* the loop completes. You cannot be sure what the value of `j` will be when the delegate is executed.

Try passing the value of `j` in as a parameter to the delegate, like this:

```
GameHistoryPicBox1[j].BeginInvoke(new Action<int>((x) =>
{
    if ((x + x / 6) % 2 == 0)
        GameHistoryPicBox1[x].Image = Properties.Resources.al1;
    else
        GameHistoryPicBox1[x].Image = Properties.Resources.al2;
}), j);
```

Answer (score 2):

You've been bitten by the loop-variable-in-a-closure-bug.

Instead of

```
for (int j = 0; j < 66; j++)
{
    //blahblahblah
}
```

write

```
for (int jj = 0; jj < 66; jj++)
{
    int j = jj;
    //blahblahblah
}
```